# Terminal apply a command to all sub directories

Tags: bash, terminal, file-rename, spaces, subdirectory

I've been working on this for a couple days and haven't been able to figure it out. Done a lot of research but nothing has worked so far so I thought I would ask. So here's where I'm at: I'm running bash 3.2.57(1)-release in terminal and was able to get this code below to work. All it does is once I've 'cd' into a folder on a file server I'm working on, it will replace any of the excess grammar with '_'. The reason for this is I'm migrating the file server from mac to Microsoft Sharepoint which doesn't like '/'.

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i//[\/<>:\\|*\'\"?]/_}"; done
```

Now I'm trying to make it so the code will run in all sub directories. The file server is very clunky and tons of the sub folders have spaces in their names which I haven't been able to get around.
Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good job on the mv synthax.

Answer (score 1):

Use find instead of for:

```
find . -type f | while read i ; do echo "$i" ; done
```

If the output of that is the list of files you wish to operate on (mod the find options if not) then replace the echo with your mv command.